# Cannot fix mouse double-click issue on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, mouse, hardware-failure

I have suffered from double clicking problem on most of single click on Windows 11 and tried to solve the problem by applying the following steps:

I have encountered this problem for my 2 different mouses:

- Logitech Wireless M185
- Logitech M305 Wireless Optical Mouse

1. Cleaning all part of the mouses by disassembling.
2. Using a new batteries
3. Checking double click settings and trying to change mouse speed on Control panel
4. Disable the USB port’s power saver settings
5. Uninstall and reinstall mouse driver
6. Changing to swap right-left click

Except from 6th step, it does not make any sense. But after swapping and trying to use with right button, it seems normal. Then, I think it my be an hardware problem. But when I encountered this problem at the same time with different mouses, I could not be sure.

So, if it is an hardware problem, what would you suggest except from cleaning mouse parts (I already did)? Or would you suggest any extra steps?

Comment: I suggest trying a new mouse which says "for Windows 11" on the package and see if that works. I think it will. Nothing wrong with Windows 11 that I can see.

Comment: I will, but do yoı have an idea to fix the mouse if the problem is hardware related?

Comment: Most mice cannot be properly repaired. Tiny circuit boards and tiny micro switches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping Just wondered if there is a quick solution, but generally it is less likely possible.

Answer (score 1):

> After swapping and trying to use with right button, it seems normal.
> Then, I think it my be an hardware problem.

I agree.

I am using modern LogiTech Bluetooth mice and USB mouse/keyboard combinations on my own Windows 11 machines.  The USB mouse is quite new (purchased with the new computer).

I suggest trying a new, good quality mouse and that should fix the issue.

Mice are not easily repaired as exact circuit boards and micro switches would be needed.

Comment: thanks chico John...